# Pop method of linked list using unique_ptr

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I'm looking at the implementation of a singly linked list using `unique_ptr` on https://solarianprogrammer.com/2019/02/22/cpp-17-implementing-singly-linked-list-smart-pointers/. My question pertains to the following method:

```
 3 struct List {
 4     List() : head{nullptr} {};
 5 
 6     // ...
 7 
 8     void pop() {
 9         if(head == nullptr) {
10             return;
11         }
12 
13         std::unique_ptr<Node> temp = std::move(head);
14         head = std::move(temp->next);
15     }
16 
17     // ...
18 };
```

I am wondering why the temporary is needed here? Why couldn't you simply do `head = std::move(head->next)`? Is this because it will result in a memory leak? When `head` is reassigned, does `unique_ptr` automatically free the current memory it's pointing to?

I was under   the impression that smart pointers are fool proof from memory leaks. It seems in this case there might be a memory leak for the original `head` because there would no longer be a smart pointer pointing to it?

Comment: There is certainly no memory leak. `unique_ptr` won't leak unless you `release()` or leak the actual pointer object. But I'm not sure if `head = std::move(head->next);` is allowed. During `head`'s assignment, it may `delete` what it points to, leading to `head->next` potentially being a dangling pointer.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux it will not be a dangling pointer. `unique_ptr::operator=` will first `release()` the `next` pointer, and then the old pointer will not be `delete`d until after that released pointer is taken ownership of.

Comment: _"... fool proof..."_ Only for well behaved fools.  Alas, very little can be done for the misbehaved fools.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for clearing that up for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am wondering why the temporary is needed here?

It is not really *needed*, but it is not *bad* to use, either.

> Why couldn't you simply do `head = std::move(head->next)`? Is this because it will result in a memory leak?

You can.  There will be no leak in this example.

> When `head` is reassigned, does `unique_ptr` automatically free the current memory it's pointing to?

Yes.  However, the old pointer will not be `delete`'d until after ownership of the new pointer is transferred first.  Per cppreference:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator%3D

> Transfers ownership from `r` to `*this` as if by calling `reset(r.release())` followed by an assignment of `get_deleter()` from `std::forward<E>(r.get_deleter())`.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset

> Replaces the managed object.
>
> 1. Given `current_ptr`, the pointer that was managed by `*this`, performs the following actions, in this order:
>
>    1. Saves a copy of the current pointer `old_ptr = current_ptr`
>    2. Overwrites the current pointer with the argument `current_ptr = ptr`
>    3. If the old pointer was non-empty, deletes the previously managed object
>       `if(old_ptr) get_deleter()(old_ptr)`.

So:

In the case where `temp` is used, the pointer to the old node in `head` will first be moved to `temp` via its move constructor, resetting `head` to hold a `nullptr`. Then `head.operator=` will call `next.release()` and acquire that pointer.  And then `temp` will go out of scope, `delete`'ing the old node.

In the case where `temp` is not used, `head.operator=` will call `next.release()`, save its old pointer and replace it with the released pointer, and then `delete` the saved pointer.

No leak either way.

> I was under the impression that smart pointers are fool proof from memory leaks.

If used *properly*, yes.

> It seems in this case there might be a memory leak for the original `head` because there would no longer be a smart pointer pointing to it?

There is no leak, as there is always a `unique_ptr` referring to the old node, until `pop()` exits and `temp` is destroyed, `delete`'ing the old node with it.  Even if `temp` is omitted, the old node is still destroyed properly after ownership of its `next` pointer is transferred.

Comment: Ah okay. I didn't initially think there would be a memory leak. The introduction of the `temp` variable gave me that impression, but it seems perhaps they just adopted the raw pointer methodology to smart pointers (i.e., the temporary would be needed if using raw pointers). Is there any benefit to using `temp` here?

Comment: @dd22205 "*Is there any benefit to using temp here?*" - not really, in this example.  It is probably just being used as a safety catch in case something goes wrong with `operator=`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau There really isn't any need for a safety catch here, since assignment for a `unique_ptr` is `noexcept`. The only benefit `temp` has here is for clarity, for those like me who wouldn't have known at first glance if it was safe to omit it.